# Can Emscripten compile LLVM to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, llvm, emscripten

I'd like to know if Emscripten is self-hosting in such a way, that it can compile LLVM to JavaScript?

Comment: By "LLVM", you mean the IR `clang++ -emit-llvm` spits out when compiling LLVM libraries?

Comment: No, by LLVM I mean the C++ code, that LLVM is written in.

Comment: Can't you simply try to compile it and see if it works?

Comment: Interesting thought. It might work (with some major rewrite, I assume) but even if, the resulting JS would probably be HUGE and slow.

Comment: Emscripten is written in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, Emscripten is. LLVM is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can as of the end of 2012.

https://github.com/kripken/llvm.js

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this question and answering :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot do that as of April 2013.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this question and answering :)