# Can Emscripten compile LLVM to JavaScript for a webbased program language

Tags: javascript, c++, c, llvm, emscripten

I'm working on my own program language which can be created in a web based editor.
I want to translate my code to LLVM-IR on client side. The IR code will be transfer, translate to instruction set and execute on an embedded device.

Well, my plan is to create a lexer, parser and code-generator in C/C++ which used the LLVM-API to create LLVM-IR code. 
Later I will translate my C/C++ code to JavaScript by using emscripten.

However i need to translate the LLVM-toolchain to JavaScript before i can convert my own project to javascript. 
But does anybody knows if it is possible to translate the LLVM to JavaScript?

I found a similar question here:
[Can Emscripten compile LLVM to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194825/can-emscripten-compile-llvm-to-javascript)

But with no clear result...

Or does anyboy have comments to my plan?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LLVM itself has been compiled, but a while ago. It would take some effort to port it now. It's also fairly large, which can be a problem in browsers.

You would also need to port parts of emscripten, which are written in python.

Overall this is all possible, but would take nontrivial effort.

Comment: Yes, that's what I through. The last port is 2 years ago. At the moment, I have only the parts compiled  which are needed to build the LLVM IR in the Browser (lib/IR and lib/Support of the LLVM Root folder). This works really good and is enough at the moment.  So, i will spend more effort to port LLVM if i needed. Thank a lot for your answer!